# How to get all remote repositories of a maven project hierarchy?

Tags: maven

I'm redirecting all maven repository access to an Artifactory with the following `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!-- unclear what version changes -> use 1.1.0 because it's higher -->
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>central</id>
      <username>admin</username>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <name>artifactory</name>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://[hostname]:[port]/artifactory/remote-repos/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>https://[hostname]:[port]/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:25200</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>https://[hostname]:[port]/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
          <snapshots />
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>https://[hostname]:[port]/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:25200</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>remote-repos</name>
          <url>https://[hostname]:[port]/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
          <snapshots />
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

and thus have to add extra remote repositories which are specified by a project  (and its child projects) to the Artifactory instance. I currently use

```
find . -name pom.xml -exec grep -B 5 -C 5 '<repository>' {} +
```

which isn't very handy in case an URL is a variable and declared elsewhere and it doesn't skip duplicates. It's not the worst thing in the world, but maybe there's an improvement available.

The following doesn't work:

- `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` doesn't display remote repositories
- `mvn dependency:list-repositories` only works until the first dependency can't be fetched if the proxy is enabled so that I have to figure out where to get it from, add the researched remote repository to Artifactory or move `~/.m2/settings.xml` aside - less handy than the `find` command above

The solution should work recursively, i.e. include all repositories in all child projects and childrens child projects, etc.

It makes a lot of sense that a solutions don't require to download the dependencies directly from the remote repository first without the proxy since I'd like to transfer them through the Maven proxy immediately if possible - it's not a requirement, though.

Comment: Some of the repositories could be declared in the dependencies. That would make you download those dependencies to find all the repositories needed..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I don't get what you mean by "Some of the repositories could be declared in the dependencies" (the `dependencies` section of the POM?).

Comment: You've got a dependency. Dependency has its own pom. In that pom you may have repositories section. To know that you'd first have to download that dependency.

Comment: But where to get the POM of the dependency from?

Comment: It will be downloaded with the dependency itself. It's just you wanted to figure out repositories without going into trouble of resolving dependencies. I'm trying to point out that you *will need* to download them.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat hacky approach could be those two steps:

1. Get the effective POMs. Note that the below goal generates an XML file containing all POMs at once. However, variable names will already be resolved.

   ```
   mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput="effective-pom.xml"
   ```
2. Parse the resulting XML file and gather the repositories, e.g., using a     Python script `gather-repos.py`.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   root = ET.parse('effective-pom.xml').getroot()
   repositories = dict()
   for node in root.iter('{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}repository'):
       repo_id = node.findtext('{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}id')
       repositories[repo_id] = node
   for node in repositories.itervalues():
       ET.ElementTree(node).write(sys.stdout, default_namespace='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0')
   ```

Of course, the script can then be run via

```
chmod +x gather-repos.py
./gather-repos.py
```

Comment: Looks like a good (although hacky - I agree) solution :) `ET.parse('tmp')` is probably `ET.parse('effective-pom.xml')` and it'd be nice if it would work recursively which it doesn't seem to as far as I tested (with https://github.com/javaee/glassfish) - I only mentioned that the problem affects child projects as well, so now I clarified that the solution should work recursively.

Comment: It has to be `effective-pom.xml`, absolutely. :) So, recursively in terms of dependencies? Maybe the script can be extended to operate recursively on POMs in the local Maven repository. If I understand your comment on `dependency:list-repositories` correctly, the `dependency` plugin fails to resolve all dependencies anyway, so that the walking of the dependency graph needs to be done "manually".

Comment: `dependency:list-repositories` only doesn't work if the proxy is enabled (in `settings.xml` like shown above)